# Changing src location of scripts C# webbrowser control

Tags: c#, browser, web, proxy, controls

So in the web browser control i am trying to update all existing links , i am currently using a proxy and it is not updating the links to scripts properly so most of the javascript fails to work.
in short, i load the page, and then one particular javascript source link is still located as "js/script.js" when it needs to be , "http://webpage.com/js/script.js".
i am unable to change the links in the document.
This is using a WebBrowser Control and a Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code example or javascripts linked in question I can give you only one best guess:

If you run javascripts which load other scripts because they require them, they'll update the html markup by maybe adding a script tag or what not. So you cannot really rely on that all scripts are statics and all links will stay as they are

For example the google map api loads tons of scripts while the initial script loads the bootstrapper only...

But as I said, this pretty much depends on what you are trying to do and your question doesn't give any hints. I can give you more information if you show me an example.